# How do i XPATH or CSS scrape a Web-Page by utilizing the drop-down menu? (Using Selenium)

Tags: python, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Okay so I'm fairly new to coding in python and I am having trouble with getting my code to fetch a url, goto it, and then using the drop-down menu i would like it to select the option "All". Which is the first selection

The website page that I am trying to scrape is: https://www.nba.com/stats/players/advanced/?sort=GP&dir=-1

My code is doing everything it's supposed to do, but whenever it does click the dropdown menu it just doesn't select the first option on the menu. I'm so confused could someone guide me help or a better/simpler route to achieve my goal.

Thanks to any helpers,

Code:

````
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import pandas as pd

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 

from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

url = r"https://www.nba.com/stats/players/advanced/?sort=GP&dir=-1"

driver.get(url)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[.='I Accept']"))).click()

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/main/div/div/div[2]/div/div/nba-stat-table/div[1]/div/div/select"))).click()```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a select class in selenium for drop down built using Select and options tag.

Once we defined webdriver wait `wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)` like this we can make use of `wait` reference type. You do not need to create WebDriverWait instance again.

**Code :**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\Inc\\Desktop\\Selenium+Python\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
driver.get("https://www.nba.com/stats/players/advanced/?sort=GP&dir=-1")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[.='I Accept']"))).click()

drop_down = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//th[text()='PACE']/ancestor::div[@class='nba-stat-table']/preceding-sibling::div/descendant::select")))
select = Select(drop_down)
select.select_by_visible_text('All')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the below Xpath

```
 (//div[@class="stats-table-pagination__info"]/select/option)[1]
```

The concept of writing a click along with WebDriverWait, this needs to be changed a little. The main reason we are adding a WebDriverWait is to wait for an element based on some condition so that it can be clicked once available. So try the below way

```
# Waiting for the element to be clickable
 1. WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//div[@class="stats-table-pagination__info"]/select/option)[1]")))

# Selecting on the element required
 2. select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@class="stats-table-pagination__info"]/select/option)[1]"))
    select.select_by_visible_text('All')
```